# Python game's world generation odd output

Tags: python, arrays, pickle

I've been making a rougelike game and I have come across a problem when saving the randomly generated world.

The following code:

```
import random import pickle

size = 6 
a = [["WHAT"]*size for x in xrange(size)] 

def make():
    for x in range(0, size):
        for z in range(0, size):
            a[x][z] =  random.choice(["T","G", "S", "M"]) 

def save():
    try:
        pickle.dump( a, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )
    except:
        print "Error" 

def load():
    a = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) ) 

def printworld():
    for x in range(0, size):
        print""
        for z in range(0, size):
            print a[x][z],
            print "", 

make() 
printworld() 
save() 
print""

make() 
printworld() 
print"" 
load() 
printworld()
```

Output the following:

```
G  G  T  M  M  S   
T  G  G  G  T  G   
T  M  S  G  M  M   
G  S  M  S  M  S   
M  S  T  M  G  T   
M  G  G  T  G  S  

G  G  S  T  T  S   
S  M  G  G  S  G   
T  M  S  G  T  M   
S  M  S  T  G  G   
M  T  S  G  M  S   
G  G  S  G  M  S  

G  G  S  T  T  S   
S  M  G  G  S  G   
T  M  S  G  T  M   
S  M  S  T  G  G   
M  T  S  G  M  S   
G  G  S  G  M  S
```

When it should have output:

```
G  G  T  M  M  S   
T  G  G  G  T  G   
T  M  S  G  M  M   
G  S  M  S  M  S   
M  S  T  M  G  T   
M  G  G  T  G  S  

G  G  S  T  T  S  
S  M  G  G  S  G   
T  M  S  G  T  M   
S  M  S  T  G  G   
M  T  S  G  M  S   
G  G  S  G  M  S  

G  G  T  M  M  S   
T  G  G  G  T  G   
T  M  S  G  M  M   
G  S  M  S  M  S   
M  S  T  M  G  T   
M  G  G  T  G  S
```

Comment: Can you please point out what is different between those two outputs, and specifically what is wrong with the current output? They seem subtly different but I'm not sure what you are expecting.

Comment: Cyber: the code print "", make() printworld() save() print""
make() printworld() print"" load() printworld() should output  a b a assuming it is a single character array but it outputs a b b. Why?

Comment: You might find it easier to test each part of this separately if you changed your functions to take explicit parameters and return appropriate values.

Comment: Would you highlight (bold/italic) the differences in the observed and expected output? Would be easier to interpret.

Comment: I was the person who edited the question -- as best as I can tell, OP is trying to create two "worlds". He saves the first one and tries to load it, but ends up getting the second world instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
def load():
    a = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
```

Here you are writing to a local variable `a`, which will then be thrown away. You need to add `global a` in order to assign a new value to a global variable.

---

In your next question please write, in words,  what the code is supposed to do and what actually happens. Here you might have written:

> This code is supposed to generate a list and save it to a file, generate a new one, and then load the original list. But after loading, when I print its value I still see the value of the second list instead of the original one.